# Using a slider to toggle between Folium feature groups

Tags: python, leaflet, mapping, gis, folium

I am making a folium map where there are multiple layers, each essentially being a raster (I brought in GeoTIFFs using Rasterio and used rasterlayers.ImageOverlay to display them on the map).

For context they are rasters symbolizing flood depths under a particular storm event.

I would like to be able to use a slider to progress between each raster, and as I move the slider ideally I'd like to slowly fade away the previous raster and show the next raster.

Is this as at all possible with folium?

I looked around at the documentation and couldn't see anything that discussed this use case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.